# Learning SQL: Narrowing down a grouped subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

[image: A list returned with the 6 parts and their average quantity]

I would like to filter this so that the final returned list only has parts with an average quantity of greater than 350 (so parts P3, P4, and P6). I have tried using the *SELECT """" WHERE AVG(spjandq.qty)>350 IN(*the entire query in the picture below*)* syntax and keep getting ERROR 1111 invalid use of group function. Could someone help point me in the right direction for the syntax to add constraints to a subquery like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just after GROUP BY pno, add:

```
HAVING AVG(spjandq.qty) > 350
```

Basically, having is the keyword to use to filter the results of aggregation.

Comment: Do the right thing and officially accept my answer. hehe